# mailx attachment behaviour between RHEL 5 and RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, email, mailx

We have a line of code that does this in ksh, to send a file as an attachment in email:

```
uuencode <filename> <filename.txt> | mailx someone@somewhere.com
```

In RHEL 5.2 `mailx` sends `filename` through as an attachment, but in 6.3 the file content arrives in the target inbox in the body of the message.
It appears that the "6.3" `mailx` only wants to send an attachment if the "-a" option is used and the content is in a file.

Does anyone know a way of getting the original behaviour?

Also I am interested to know why this behaviour has changed.

Comment: From the first paragraph of the man page:  "It is based on Berkeley Mail 8.1".  So that explains the change to the way it works.